# File (Field) Path settings to rename multiple images with their alt or title

Tags: 8, files, tokens

The module [File (Field) Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) allows me quite nice to rename a single image file with its "alt" or "title". But if allow the image field to accept multiple downloads, I cannot get the individual alt/title for each file (with some kind of loop) as there seems no variable token for the delta. Am I missing something or is there really no chance to rename the files that way?